# FileSystemInfo to string array

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to know what the most efficient way of converting a FileSystemInfo to a string array is - My code as is follows:

```
    string[] filePaths;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(batchDirectory);
    FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
    filePaths = files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);
```

I tried:

```
filePaths = files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime).ToArray;
```

but had no luck

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
filePaths = files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime).Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parenthesis () to Array;

```
 files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime).ToArray();
```

Comment: That wouldn't give a string array though but is a good observation. :)

Comment: Thank you Chris, Daniel bring solution complete